# Sampling based on dependent data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

My data frame consist 10M records with 6 columns. The class(is_active) is very imbalanced (1-96%,0-4%).

Data frame looks like -

```
id      age    gender    salary   bonus  is_active
1        27     M         76543    762     0
2        36     F         87352    1050    1
3        29     M         76598    7364    1
4        61     M         74632    3475    0
```

I want a data frame where my dependent variable (is_active) ration should be 1-75%,0-25%.

How to do it in python?

Comment: split your df into two based on is_active. then use sample with 0.75 and 0.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be trying this,

```
df_1 = df[df['is_active']==1]
df_2 = df[df['is_active']==0]
df_1= df_1.sample(n = len(df_2)*3)
df=pd.concat([df_1, df_2], ignore_index=True)
```

1. split your dataframe into two parts based on is_active.
2. take all rows in negative sample.
3. perform sampling of df_2 based on length of df_1
4. concat the both dataframes.

Last test:

```
print (df['is_active'].value_counts(normalize=True))
```

Comment: @jezrael - Can you please explain df_1= df_1.sample(n = len(df_2)*3)...because if I want to do 60:40 then what should I do?is there any formula is present?

Comment: @JohnDavis - formula is `1/.25` it is `4`, so for you `int(1 / 0.4)`